# Why are we subtracting 1 from this probability?

Tags: statistics

So I have an issue with problems a, b & h. My work is correct up to a certain point but then they subtract 1 whereas I left it as is. Could someone please explain why we subtract 1 from the answers of a, b & h to get the correct answer but we do not do that for problem c?

Thank you!

[image]
[image]

Comment: The table tells you the probability that $Z<1.98$, which is $0.9761$. You want $P(Z>1.98)$.

Comment: Then how come we didn't have to do that for problem c?

Comment: I don't know. Are you _certain_ you didn't have to?

Comment: Yeah, that's where I got confused too. For c, I just checked with the chi square table and then when I checked the answer that was it. I didn't need to subtract anything. Or I mean my answer matched up so I assume I didn't have to?

Comment: @NookLines You appear to be using different tables.  If so, then carefully check what they tell you they are measuring.

Comment: @GrahamKemp aHHHH okayyyy, thank you for the direction, chi square tables give you values to the right, z score tables give you values to the left

Comment: Even without looking at the tables it would be impossible to have a standard normal  r.v. with prob. $Z$ higher than almost 2 stdeviations at 97%